# Define a differentiable bijection

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do I define;

- a bijection which is also differentiable from $\{ (x,y) | x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ to $\mathbb R^2 $.

and

- a bijection which is also differentiable from a bounded non-convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2 $.

Would I use continuity on the first part?

Would $ f(x,y)=(2x+3y,x+2y) $ be a viable answer for the second one?

Any help or answers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the identity not count?

Comment: For the first part, you can think about stretching the unit disc out by some factor that approaches infinity as $x^2 + y^2$ approaches 1.  In other words, try to think of a mapping that sends $(x, y) \mapsto (k(x, y)\cdot x, k(x, y)\cdot y)$, where $k(x,y)$ is a function that approaches infinity as $(x, y)$ approaches the unit circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

$f(x,y)=\left(x\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right),y\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right)$

For the second part, try a bijective map of the 2/3 of the disk (non-convex and bounded) into the full disk with a function $g$:

[image]

by preserving the magnitude, and multiplying the angle by 3/2.

Then $g\circ f$ will be a bijections from the 2/3 of the disk into $\mathbb R^2$

In polar coordinates:

Answer to the first question:

$f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi r}{2}\right)\cos\theta,\tan\left(\frac{\pi r}{2}\right)\sin\theta\right)$ with $0\le r<1$ and $0\le\theta<2\pi$

Mapping from sector to unit ball:

$g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\left(r\cos\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right), r\cos\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right)\right)$ with $0\le r<1$ and $0\le\theta<\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Answer to the second question $h=f\circ g$:

$h(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi r}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right), \tan\left(\frac{\pi r}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{3\theta}{2}\right)\right)$  with $0\le r<1$ and $0\le\theta<\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Comment: For the first part, right?

Comment: Is $ f(x,y)=(2x+3y,x+2y) $ okay for the second answer?

Comment: What you wrote for the second part is a bijection from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$. But $\mathbb R^2$ is not bounded. And if you restrict the domain to a non-convex subset $A\subset\mathbb R^2$ it would no longer be bijective. So your example is not good.

Comment: I edited my answer for the second part. I hope you will be able to work out the details. If the answer is useful for you,  please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Would an acceptable answer for the second part be $ \{f(rcos\theta,rsin\theta) |0\leq r\leq 1,0\leq\theta\leq\frac{2\pi}{3}\} $ to the unit disk? Sorry for all my questions, I just want to make sure I've got it right. Thank for for all your help!

Comment: *** or $\frac{4\pi}{3} $ rather

Comment: I put the polar coordinates at the end of my answer. I think it's more clear.

Comment: I think the second question would be more satisfying if it was defined on an open subset rather than one with a partial boundary.

Comment: @Erik Wong OP did not request it to be a open set. But if you want, you can construct a bijective map of the unit ball into an open set bounded by a curve such as [$r=2+\cos3\theta$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D2%2Bcos%283theta%29). So you would have $g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=(r(2+\cos3\theta)\cos\theta,r(2+\cos3\theta)\sin\theta)$

Comment: Then, $f\circ g^{-1}$ would do what you want.